# javascript counting vowels, consonants and show the occurrance

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble to figure out how to count vowels, consonants and declare how often the vowels appears separately, from user input.
The user put any text ex: “Mischief managed!” and result must be:
a: 2
e: 2
i: 2
o: 0
u: 0
non-vowels: 11

```
var userData = prompt ("Enter any text here");
var a = 0;
var e = 0;
var i = 0;
var o = 0;
var u = 0;
var consonants = 0;
var count;

for (count = 0; count <= userData.legth; count++){
   if((userData.charAt(count).match(/[aeiou]/))){       
     a++;
     e++;
     i++;
     o++;
     u++;
    }else if((userData.charAt(count).match(/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ]/))){

    consonants++;
}
}
 console.log ("a: " + a);
 console.log ("e: " + e);
 console.log ("i: " + i);
 console.log ("o: " + o);
 console.log ("u: " + u);
 console.log ("consonants: " + consonants);
```

But it's not working. I already searched in many other forums but, I didn't find anything like this.

Comment: For starters learn to use browser dev tools to check for errors and to set breakpoints for debugging. `userData.legth` will be undefined as it should be `userData.length`. Logic off adding to each vowel counter for any match doesn't make sense either. You never check specific vowel matches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, let's point out some things

```
for (count = 0; count <= userData.legth; count++){
```

*Length* is missing letter *'n'* and you don't need count to be less than or equal because you already start from index 0. So you just need *less than*.

Also:

```
if((userData.charAt(count).match(/[aeiou]/))){       
    a++;
    e++;
    i++;
    o++;
    u++;
} else if((userData.charAt(count).match(/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ]/))){
    consonants++;
}
```

What you are doing here is that every time it matches a vowel, you increment the variable for all of them, so for the word ***hi*** it would print that every vowel had one count. So take a look at this one:

```
var userData = prompt("Enter any text here").toLowerCase();
var a = 0;
var e = 0;
var i = 0;
var o = 0;
var u = 0;
var consonants = 0;
var count;

for (count = 0; count < userData.length; count++){
    var char = userData.charAt(count);
    if(char.match(/[aeiou]/)){
        switch (char) {
            case 'a':
                a++;
                break;
            case 'e':
                e++;
                break;
            case 'i':
                i++;
                break;
            case 'o':
                o++;
                break;
            case 'u':
                u++;
                break;
        }
    } else if(char.match(/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/)) {
        consonants++;
    }
}

console.log ("a: " + a);
console.log ("e: " + e);
console.log ("i: " + i);
console.log ("o: " + o);
console.log ("u: " + u);
console.log ("consonants: " + consonants);
```

I am following your logic to keep it simple and better readable for you. We match the regular expression the same way you do, but we also check what is the exact character right now, so we can increment the correct variable.

For the ***else if***, in order to minimize a bit your regular expression we just check if it matches one of the lower case letters, because we convert the userData to lower case, as soon as we get it:

```
var userData = prompt("Enter any text here").toLowerCase();
```

Try my example and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: How do you expect to return data when all your vars are evaluated?

Comment: @AlexKudryashev I replied to the question given without a function so there is no return obviously. I created a working example that is relevant to the code posted, so that he can understand the concept and what mistakes he did because he seems to be missing some of the basics. Once he gets hold of the basics, he can then try and of course create a function. So my code is not a function but it can be part of one.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev a simple idea would be to return an object whose properties would be each one of the vowels and one for consonants.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to check which vowel you're encountering and then update
the appropriate variable.

But `for` is rarely needed. JavaScript provides higher-level array
iteration functions which among other things, will prevent mistakes such
as off-by-one errors, like you have in your code :-)

And though your input is a string, not an array, you can turn it
into one by using
[`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

```js
var input = 'Mischief managed!';

var result = input.split('').reduce(function(result, c){
    c = c.toLowerCase();
    if(c in result){
        result[c] += 1;
    }else{
        result.other += 1;
    }
    return result;
}, {a:0, e:0, i:0, o:0, u:0, other:0});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

I've used [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) here, but you may,
initially, find [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) easier to
get your head around.

Answer (score 1):

Well for the sake of better coding and performance i would do this like this;

```js
var str = "the quick brown fOx jUmps OvEr the lazy dog";

function getVowelCount(s) {
  var lut = {
      a: "0",
      e: "0",
      i: "0",
      o: "0",
      u: "0"
    },
    a = s.split("").map(c => c.toLowerCase());
  return a.reduce((p, c) => (p[c] && 1 * p[c]++, p), lut);
}
console.log(getVowelCount(str));
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use regular expression to match vowels in a string.

**Regular expression to match all occurrence of vowel in a string:*/[aeiouAEIOU]+?/g***

> Below is the working code snippet:

```
    //function that takes string as input
    //function returns an object containing vowel count without case in account.
    function vowelCount(input) {
        //to get vowel count using string.match
        var arrVowels =input.match(/[aeiouAEIOU]+?/g);

        //acc=accumulator, curr=current value
        var countVowCons= arrVowels.reduce(function (acc, curr) {
           if (typeof acc[curr.toLowerCase()] == 'undefined') {
               acc[curr.toLowerCase()] = 1;
           } 
           else {
               acc[curr.toLowerCase()] += 1;
           }
           return acc;
           // the blank object below is default value of the acc (accumulator)
           }, {}); 

        countVowCons.NonVowels= input.match(/[^aeiouAEIOU]+?/g).length;
        return countVowCons;        
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```js
var userData = prompt("Enter any text here"),
    count = userData.split('').reduce(function (r, a) {
        var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'],
        p = vowels.indexOf(a.toLowerCase());
    if (~p) {
        r[vowels[p]] = (r[vowels[p]] || 0) + 1;
    } else {
        r['non-vowels']= (r['non-vowels']|| 0) + 1;
    }
    return r;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

First count all letters and then filter what you need.

```
function cntLetters(inp){
  var result={};
  var vowels = 'aeiouy'.split('');
  var inpArr=inp.split('');
  for(var i=0,n=inpArr.length;i<n;i++){
    result[inpArr[i]] = (result[inpArr[i]]||0)+1;
    if(vowels.indexOf(inpArr[i]) > -1)
       result['vowels'] = (result['vowels'] || 0) + 1;
  }
  return result;
}
var cnt = cntLetters('see your later');
console.log(cnt['a']);
console.log(cnt['e']);
```

If you want case-insensitive use `var inpArr=inp.toLowerCase().split('');`

Comment: And the total for non-vowels?

Comment: Add `var nonVowelArr = ['b','c','d'];` Add line inside `for` `if(nonVowelArr.indexOf(inpArr[i] > -1) result['nonVowel']=(result['nonVowel']||0)+1;`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
var alpha = function(){      
  this.a = 0;
  this.e = 0;
  this.i = 0;
  this.o = 0;
  this.u = 0;
  this.other = 0;    
}

function counter(word, alpha) {
  for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    var chr = word.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
    if (alpha.hasOwnProperty(chr)) {
      alpha[chr]++;
    } else {
      alpha.other++;
    }
  }
}

function checkWord()
{
  var a = new alpha();
  counter("test", a); 
  console.log(a);         
}
```

In action can be seen in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sc2kcYkHTAIJEyhky5Nh?p=preview)

Comment: You need a `new alpha()` somewhere. You may as well just use an object literal.

Comment: The new() was in the plunker ex.. i didnt use obj lit, so would not have to worry about resetting the object on multiple usages

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do it, but the general idea of splitting the text, looping through each letter and counting the vowels is similar to what others are posting about as well.

```js
getCount = (str) => {
  var vowelsCount = 0;
  str = str.split('');
    for(var i = 0; i<str.length; i++) {
      if(str[i] === "a" || str[i] === "e" || str[i] === "i" || str[i] === "o" || str[i] === "u"){
        vowelsCount++;
    }
  }
  return vowelsCount;
}

console.log(getCount('onomatopoeia'));
```